# How to get a direct link to a Google+ review (including mobile)?

Tags: google-plus

I used to use these types of links to leave Google+ reviews, it even worked on mobile. It still works on Desktop, just not on mobile.

https://plus.google.com/+Fidleronthetooth/about?fd=1&review=1

I am looking for a linking solution for Desktop and Mobile that will take me directly to leaving a review, without the need to click any additional buttons/links.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a site-specific URL scheme, not programming.  It appears that [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) encompasses review features on Google sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for the business that you are trying to find the link for. Then once you have found it, click "write a review" on the far right. On Desktop you will receive a link.

This link alone will not work for all devices, browsers etc... So remove everything but the query, the lrd and the CID.

For info on how to find those look here: http://www.uksbd.co.uk/how-to-find-your-lrd-number/

So it would look like this if you searched for "Fidler On The Tooth" DDS:

https://www.google.com/search?q=Fidler%20On%20the%20Tooth&ludocid=8488539899762533828#lrd=0x0:0x75cd5a108b1365c4,1

Also make sure after it is the google.com/search? if it says google.com/webhp? change it to search.

One easy website that also works nicely to create the link for you is here: https://www.grade.us/home/labs/google-review-link-generator

That should work for you!

Comment: It appears the link will also work without the word 'search', like so:

https://www.google.com/#q=fidler+on+the+tooth&lrd=0x54901484a5f8d7ef:0x75cd5a108b1365c4,2

Note the `/#q=` and lack of `?`.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2016,  the new way to get the direct link is to :

1. go to google + business page
2. add ?review=1 to url

something like https://plus.google.com/1145614355408?review=1